# How to overcome issues causes of toList()

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

It reaches before `toList()` ,I checked adding `doOnEvent()` but after `toList()` it doesn't work and list contain 5 items,5 items are emitted but it doesn't go further then `toList()`

```
   return userDatas()
        .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
        .flatMap(userData -> userDao.getInfo(userData.getId())
            .map(user -> user.toStoreModel(...)
            .toList()
            .map(UserModel::fromUserModels)
            .toFlowable();




  public Flowable<List<UserData>> userDatas() {
return userDao.allUser()
.take(1)
.filter(userDatas -> !userDatas.isEmpty())
.switchIfEmpty(userDataIds()
    .doOnNext(userStores -> userStoreDao.insert(userStores)));}
```

I have added doOnNext and doOnComplete after every action and after flatMap(userData -> userDao.getInfo(userData.getId()) doOnNext works for 5 times ,but it doesn't call doOnComplete I couldn't understand if it needs to emit 5 times in that case why it doesn't call doOnComplete()

Comment: Why do you need to `toList()` there if you keep mapping ?

Comment: @alfasin Because UserModel::fromUserModels accepts list as argument and returns list

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that `userDao.getInfo()`'s Observable (or one of the other observables) does not complete. [`toList()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#toList()) can only function if the source is finite (i.e. it completes). Otherwise it would have no idea whether it has all the items that belong in the list or not.

For example, if you have a Room DAO that has a method that returns a `Flowable`, that [Flowable](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757) will never complete. It actively watches the database for changes and emits updated queries as necessary.

As another example, what would you expect the following list to contain?

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .toList()
```

The answer is you can't do that because the list would be infinite.

Comment: I see the toList() works if it completes, 
but before toList() I added doOnEvent() it works for 5 times and my list contains 5 items, but never calls doOnComplete() 
I don't understand why?

Comment: @A.A.I.A to help you understand that, you would need to include details on how you are creating these Observables. I mentioned a few cases that would cause an Observable to not complete. If those don't fit, please provide more information.

Comment: you mentioned room DAO that has a method that returns a Flowable ,that Flowable will never complete. yes but what could be the solution in that case

Comment: Without seeing all of the sources for the Observables, it is still hard to diagnose. If you have an Observable that doesn't complete there are a number of options based on the desired behavior. `first()` and `take()` would be two options.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Room database.
Try to use Single instead of Flowable when you call first database method.

```
userDao.allUser() - should return Single<List<UserModel>>
```

Then convert to Flowable

```
userDao.allUser().toFlowable()
```

After that you can receive your list as you did in your example

```
.toList()
.map(UserModel::fromUserModels)
.toFlowable();
```